# install python3.8 but not found include folders

Tags: python, youcompleteme

I am trying to fix a issue of YouCompleteMe when run install.py in linux.

It says ERROR: Python headers are missing in /usr/include/python3.8
So I try to install python3.8 with:

```
sudo apt install python3.8
```

Command is success but that include folder still not there, I can only see 2.7 and 3.5 folders:

```
python2.7/  python3.5/  python3.5m/
```

What's the reasone 3.5 folders is there but 3.8 folders not?

Comment: Have you been following the [instructions](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#linux-64-bit)?

Comment: Yes, it says install python3-dev, but when I install it, it installed python3.5 actually. then the setup.py try to access python3.8 so it fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying version.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

Above line helped me to get include folder for python version 3.8

Comment: It seems like the original author already tried that - is there something else that needed to be done?

Comment: @EricJin I think, author tried with "python3.8" and "python3-dev" only and not the way I mentioned. Kindly check that.